# Email sent using node mailer to ses forwarder is marked as spam

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, spam, amazon-ses, nodemailer

i'm using nodemailer (smtp transport) to send emails to a AWS SES email address (from and to contain the same domain).

On email receiving the email is stored on s3 and then a lambda function forwards this email to my private email address (using https://github.com/arithmetric/aws-lambda-ses-forwarder)

If I send an email using nodemailer, this email is marked as spam on my private email account, but if I not use nodemailer (eg using my private account), it's not marked.

I hope you can help me :)

PS: If you need any further information just let me know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about email deliverability, not about programming. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Answer (score 0):

This will be down to the 'reputation' of the email and could be based on a number of factors;

1. IP Address
2. SPF Setup
3. DKIM setup
4. Sender Address

This not an AWS issue.